# HTML target="_top" inside an IFRAME Not Working for Some Links

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am seeing strange situation [here](http://fr.cars.yahoo.com/footer/). This was meant for including in Iframe. Every links in it is set for target=_top with Javascript. It was working fine but not now. I checked in FF 11.

There are 3 columns (Yahoo! Auto, Services Yahoo! and Tendances Du Web). In 1st column, all links work (use target=_top) except "Neuf et occasion". On other columns, no link is respecting target="_top". I guess it is JavaScript onclick event which is causing problem, but How to be sure of it! There are so many lines of code in JavaScript that is in minified form.

**The above frame is used [here](http://auto.yahoo.fr/) inside Iframe**. So, you can check the working code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting the console reveals that your page has several JavaScript errors of this form:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://auto.yahoo.fr/ from frame with URL
>   http://fr.cars.yahoo.com/footer/. Domains, protocols and ports must
>   match.

The reason for this error is because it is considered a security problem to have frames accessing different domains. 'Accueil', 'News' and 'Essais' work because they point to a relative path (same domain), but 'Neuf et occasion' points to a different domain.

A solution would be to rewrite your footer to not use an iframe. This way you won't have any more cross-domain issues with the links. If you can't remove the iframe, you could investigate using [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) to communicate between the frames.

Comment: Yes, I cannot remove Iframe. I will check for easyXDM as you have suggested and post comment here soon.

Comment: Do you have example of easyXDM only for Iframe target thing to work?  I am asking as I saw few example for sending message between provider and consumer. For me, I just need to make link load on _top.

Comment: Can crossdomain.xml help me here? I can possibly module the file at far.cars.yahoo.com/.

Comment: I saw that it was due to tracker changing links in background and  adding click event to change there as well. Frame target=_top is working fine without that.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash different context that OP, but your comment saved me from going insane nonetheless, thank you! in my case plausible.io outbound link tracking broke `target="_top"` behavior in iframe content. have one internet on me, friend